# Setting leftBarButtonItem vertical position

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to give the leftBarButtonItem a top margin but it doesn't work. I can move it to the right but not down.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(10, 20), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

The horizontal parameter `10` does work and it moves the title to the right.
But the vertical parameter `20` doesn't do anything no matter what number I change it to.

Whole code:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.ioniconOfSize(24)] as Dictionary!
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: String.ioniconWithName(Ionicon.ChevronLeft), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(5, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(5, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: OP wants Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: Still same problem. Maybe I should mention that I am using a custom font.